# Fully Transparent Action bar on Holo Light Theme

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to make full translucent action bar like google did, i tried several option, that seems to work on Holo, however they are not "full transparent" in Holo.Light
this is my style so far:

```
  <style name="MyTheme.Translucent" >
          <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
          <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and in Oncreate:

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

the result its "almost" what i need
however i see a shade in action bar:
[image]
What i want (or something like this)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found the solution
using

```
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

will do the trick to remove the line

Answer (score 0):

please check the link....................

http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level

```
                      **values/themes.xml**

<style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar" />

<style name="Theme.TranslucentActionBar.ActionBar.Overlay">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.ActionBar.Transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

                        **values/styles.xml**
     <style name="Widget.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.ActionBar.Transparent">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: i included the contents.

Comment: i tried this, it works on Holo but not in holo.light :( i have the same result